# nodejs doesn't connect to any other port

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, chat

I am trying to create a small chat app using express and nodejs over https. The problem is it doesn't connect to any port other than 3000. When i create the server it does start listening but it doesn't connect from client side. I have tried all the possible solutions found over internet but all in vain. If anyone can reproduce the issue. Will be a big help. It works perfect on port 3000. But ideally I need to make it work on 443 but right now its not working on any port other than 3000.

Server Side:

```
var fs = require('fs');
//var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
    });
 /*app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app.php');
    });
*/
// your express configuration here

//var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);


var io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);
//httpServer.listen(3001);
httpsServer.listen(3001,function(){
                                 console.log('Listening');
                                 });
httpsServer.on('listening', function() {
    console.log('Express server started on port %s at %s', httpsServer.address().port, httpsServer.address().address);
});
```

Client Side:

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io.connect('//192.168.14.85:3001');
```

Comment: You need root access for port 80 and 443. `sudo node server.js`

Comment: I am working on windows. Running it through forever module and command prompt

Comment: you might need elevated access on cmd, `Win+X` then `A` while on desktop

Comment: Is there a way to have both websockets and web traffic on same port i.e 443?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the server i was trying to run was allowing only port 80 and port 443 and both of these require root access.